# Closure of a compact set in Regular space $ X $

Tags: general-topology

I am trying to show that closure of a compact set in a Regular space is compact, but I am hitting some hurdles as a compact set in a regular space need not be closed. 
This is what I started off with: If $ C $ is any compact subset,
let $ U $ be any open neighbourhood containing $ C $. Then by regularity of $ X $, $ \forall x \in C, \exists V_x : \overset-V_x \subseteq U $ where $ V_x $ is a neighbourhood of $ x $.
So $ \lbrace  V_x:x \in C\rbrace $ is an open cover for C, which by compactness of C , simplifies to $ \lbrace  V_{x_i}:x_i \in C\,\,for\,i=1,...,n\rbrace $. Now I end up looking at $ \cup \overset-V_{x_i} $ which  should contain $ \overset-C $. But I get stuck here. Should I look at the intersection rather??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint:** Suppose that $\mathcal{U} = \{ U_i : i \in I \}$ is any cover of $\overline{C}$ by open subsets of $X$.  For each $i \in I$ and $x \in U_i$ by regularity fix an open set $V_{i,x}$ such that $x \in V_{i,x} \subseteq \overline{V_{i,x}} \subseteq U_i$.  Note that $$\mathcal{V} = \{ V_{i,x} : i \in I, x \in U_i \}$$ is also a cover of $\overline{C}$ by open subsets of $X$.  More importantly, $\mathcal{V}$ covers the compact set $C$.

Answer (score 4):

This following holds in a regular space $X$.

**Lemma:** Every open neighborhood $U$ of a compact set $K$ contains the closure $\overline K$ as well as a closed neighborhood of $K$.
**Proof:** Since $X$ is regular, every $x\in K$ has an open neighborhood $V_x$ such that $\overline {V_x}\subseteq U$. The family $\{V_x\mid x\in K\}$ is an open cover of $K$ which by compactness has a finite subcover $\{V_i,\dots,V_n\}$. Since closure commutes with finite unions, we know that $\bigcup_{i=1}^n V_i$ is a neighborhood of $K$ whose closure $\overline{\bigcup_{i=1}^n V_i}=\bigcup_{i=1}^n\overline {V_i}$ is a subset of $U$ and contains $\overline K$.

**Corollary:** The closure of a compact set $K$ is also compact.
**Proof:** An open cover of $\overline K$ is an open cover of $K$, so it has a finite subcover which by the lemma also covers $\overline K$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the last statement however, I couldn't comprehend.

Comment: @Vishesh:  A cover of $\overline K$ is also a cover of $K$, which has a finite subcover. This subcover is an open set around $K$ and by the above lemma it covers $\overline K$.

Comment: Please, all great except I don't understand why every point in a compact set has a neighbourhood whose CLOSURE in inside the open neighbourhood of the compact set. Thx

Comment: Actually isn't this a bit far fetched ? Since every singleton is compact, being regular implies being Hausdorff, thus compact sets are all closed.

Comment: @JamesWell. I don't understand your reasoning. Could you add more details and explain which of my statements you are using where?

Comment: @Stefan Hamcke : If I'm not mistaken, regular space means any compact set and any singleton can be seperated. But in any topological space, finite subsets are always compact. Therefore, in a regular space, any two singletons can be separated, which makes the regular space a Hausdorff space. It can easily be proven that in a Hausdorff space, any compact subset is closed, hence the closure of the compact subset is itself, which means the closure is compact. I hope I haven't made any stupid mistakes in this reasoning but I really don't think so ;)

Comment: @JamesWell. Regular means any closed set and any singleton can be seperated.Or Equivalently, every neighborhood of a point contains a closed neighborhood.

Comment: Ooh yes .... old memories. My mistake.